# nightwatch set value to date input is failing for google chrome

Tags: nightwatch.js

I have a uncovered a browser issue testing with `nightwatch` when setting date values in date inputs i.e. `input type="date`

For google chrome issuing the command via nightwatch
`.setValue('input[name="coursework_list_DueDate_date_start"]', '2018-06-05')`
will put nonsense into the date. This is working fine for edge and firefox.

To work around the issue What I would like to do is execute some js code within the test like this:

```
browser.waitForElementPresent('#coursework_list_search', 5000)
      .assert.elementPresent('#coursework_list_search')
      .end()

//use the dom to set the value
var dateControl = browser.getElementByName('coursework_list_DueDate_date_start');
      dateControl.value = '2017-06-01';

//continue with nightwatch
browser.click('#search').end()
```

This will give me an error stating document is undefined.

Any ideas how I can get this date entered (without falling back to regular text input??)

Answer (score 0):

I switched the input text around and it works:

`.setValue('input[name="coursework_list_DueDate_date_start"]', '05-06-2018')`